# How to show monthly data on diagram in Power BI from datetime

Tags: datetime, powerbi

I have historical daily gold prices in excel and I load them to the Power BI. But in default, Power BI shows me only year based value, but for year 2016 i have values only for January and February and therefore diagram is distorted as you can see below.

[image]

Base data looks like (can be downloaded [here](http://uloz.to/xpgBpgSm/gold-daily-value-csv) in .csv)

[image]

Visual setting is

[image]

And i want to see diagram curve to be done by months to prevent distortion.

Curve should be similar to this diagram
[image]

There are years only as a description

Thank you for help

Comment: You can create a new column that contains value of month and Year, for examples 2015 - 01  and create graph on it

Comment: Your download link site was a bit scary - can you put that file somewhere "safer" e.g. OneDrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PBI is has generated a Date Hierarchy with only a Year level.  I can tell that from the word "Year" appearing under on the Visualizations pane, under "Date" (in the Axis Section).

I would click the small down-arrow to the right of "Date", in the Axis section.  I would change that setting from "Date Hierarchy" to "Date".  This will plot every daily value on the chart.

Unfortunately you cant control the date format used in the X-Axis labels - hopefully they will add that in some future release.  Their automatic labeling is usually OK.

Comment: This really gave me headaches.. Works perfectly now, thanks!